# getting false data from fprintf

Tags: c

My script takes an input file and the file looks like this.

```
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   nonsense_mediated_decay exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000126746"; exon_number "11"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-015";
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   nonsense_mediated_decay exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000132893"; exon_number "17"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-003";
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   protein_coding  exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000066391"; exon_number "22"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-001";
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   protein_coding  exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000081318"; exon_number "23"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-017";
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   protein_coding  exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000093407"; exon_number "16"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-202";
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   protein_coding  exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000101649"; exon_number "22"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-203";

chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   protein_coding  exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000101655"; exon_number "22"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-020";
chr11   3037016 chr11_3037016   8   39  6   44  4   24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30  11  18
chr11   protein_coding  exon    3036949 3037109 .   -   .    gene_id "ENSMUSG00000023764"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000140846"; exon_number "20"; gene_name "Sfi1"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "Sfi1-016";
```

Here is my script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
   static const char filename[] = "input_file.txt";
   FILE *file3 = fopen("thirdstep2a.txt","w");
   FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

   if ( file != NULL )
   {

      char line[BUFSIZ],line2[BUFSIZ] ;
      char one[20], three[22], four[20], a1[20],a2[20],a3[20],a4[20],a5[20],a6[20],a7[20],a8[20], a9[20], a10[20],a11[20],a12[20],a13[20],a14[20],a15[20],a16[20],a17[20],a18[20],a19[20],a20[20],a21[20],a22[20],a23[20],a24[20],a25[20],a26[20],a27[20],a28[20],a29[20],a30[20],a31[20],a32[20],a33[20],a34[20];

      char one2[20],three2[20],four2[26], six2[26], seven2[20], eight2[11], nine2[20];

     fgets(line, sizeof line, file);
     fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file);
     while(1)
     {
         sscanf(line, "%19s %21s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s %19s", one, three, four, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34);
         sscanf(line2, "%*s %*s %10s %19s %19s %*s %*s %*s %*s %25s %*s %25s %*s %19s %*s %19s", eight2, one2, three2, four2, six2, seven2, nine2); 

         fprintf(file3,"%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s \t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t", one, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34);

         fprintf(file3,"%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t\n", four2, six2, seven2, one2, three2);
         if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL)
             break;

         if(fgets(line2, sizeof line, file) == NULL)
             break;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      perror(filename);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000126746";   "11";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000132893";   "17";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000066391";   "22";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000081318";   "23";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000093407";   "16";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000101649";   "22";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000101655";   "22";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000140846";   "20";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000153425";   "21";   3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000137633";   "3";    3036949     3037109    
chr11    8   39  6   44  "Sfi1";     24  7   22  6   31  7   44  8   39  13  41  10  37  9   23  18  32  8   37  2   9   16  33  9   29  4   7   5   30 "ENSMUSG00000023764";    "ENSMUST00000138126";
```

As you can see that my output does not look right. I am getting some false data from a5 string. I could not figure out the error.

Comment: Okay, about the formatting issues: First of all, **DON'T** use backticks for every line of code. Instead, copy-paste the code in, highlight it all, and then press the code (`{}`) button. You can do the same thing with the other blocks you've got, but I opted for `pre` as it doesn't have syntax highlighting.

Comment: Those are ***horrible*** names for your variables.

Comment: I fixed the code as best I could.   But chris is right, learn the formatting tools here, and DON"T use backticks so much.

Comment: Anyway, getting to the point now, `Too Localized: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; ... an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet`. As it is, it's hard to pull any information. To better remedy this, it would be very helpful if instead of a huge file we have no clue about and the code that has to go through it, you could create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your problem. Break your code down until all irrelevant details are gone and use a small file meant for the problem specifically.

Comment: First, get yourself an IDE with a good debugger (I use NetBeans and Cygwin for Windows). That will help you tremendously.  

Thirdly, use meaningful variable names (one, three, five, four??).  

Fourthly, since much of your data appears to be numeric, use %d in your format strings.  

Fifthly, your file appears to have a blan line at line 13.  

Sixthly, you don't need those double quote or semi-colons in your data file.

Answer (score 3):

When the code is compiled (in a file `bio.c`), the compiler says:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99  bio.c -o bio  
bio.c: In function ‘main’:
bio.c:24: warning: too few arguments for format
bio.c:24: warning: too few arguments for format
bio.c:17: warning: unused variable ‘two2’
bio.c:15: warning: unused variable ‘five’
bio.c:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’
$
```

I can't be bothered to work out more precisely where the problem is (line 24 is the `sscanf()` for `line2`), but the warning indicates that the code is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Read you compiler output.  GCC gives this

```
../../../vmc/_tests/chom.c:23:10: warning: too few arguments for format
../../../vmc/_tests/chom.c:23:10: warning: too few arguments for format
../../../vmc/_tests/chom.c:16:22: warning: unused variable ‘two2’
../../../vmc/_tests/chom.c:14:32: warning: unused variable ‘five’
../../../vmc/_tests/chom.c:8:8: warning: unused variable ‘i’
```

You want to be particularly worried about the first two.

Comment: i just cleared all the warnings.

Comment: and does it work now? If not, is the problem still the same, or has it changed?